# How to programmatically add to an array in database from frontend React

Tags: reactjs

I basically have this route

```
app.post("/order/:orderId/:productId", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.orderId,
    {
      $push: {
        products: req.params.productId
      }
    },
    { new: true }
  );
  res.send(result);
});
```

I have two collections, namely Product and Orders. The goal is to get, for instance, a particular Order with id(5ddfc649e1e9e31220ce6a16) ,  and post a product with id(5de02c4a0ed3160368b9a550) inside an Array field inside this Orders collection. In Postman, I can do that manually by just adding the ObjectIds in the URL like so:

```
Http://localhost:3000/orders/5ddfc649e1e9e31220ce6a16/5de02c4a0ed3160368b9a550.
```

and I get this Response :

```
{
    "products": [
        "5ddfb388b14c5b41e0607a5e",
        "5de02c4a0ed3160368b9a550" // newly added Product


    ],
    "_id": "5ddfc649e1e9e31220ce6a16",
    "issuedBy": "issuedBy",
    "collectedBy": "collectedBy",
    "quantity": 123,
    "createdAt": "2019-11-28T11:48:40.500Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-11-28T11:59:51.659Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

My challenge is, how do I do this programmatically from the UI(Reactjs) side?

```
// Product Schema

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    description: String,
    price: Number,
    quantity: Number,
    supplier: String
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);

// Orders Schema

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    issuedBy: String,
    collectedBy: String,
    quantity: Number,
    products: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Product",
        required: true
      }
    ]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);
```

I would really appreciate any suggestion or a sample code snippet

Comment: Didn't understand, what is the issue? What is it that is not getting done?

Comment: @gprathour I want the user to be able to perform this task from the front end. basically, How do i hit this route from the Frontend with both objectIds inserted in the URL

Comment: Do you mean that front end application could directly update database? If yes, why so? If no, then what do you mean by perform this task from front end?

Comment: There are two params that need to be supplied before the final task is done, these params are " :orderId '' and " productId" .My question is how do i create a UI that gets the Ids from the frontend before performing the final task of including the product  in the orders collection ?

Comment: @gprathour sorry if i  am sounding Off , relatively new with the MERN stack

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is, you need to hit this API from your front end i.e. React app.

```
http://localhost:3000/orders/<order-id-here>/<product-id-here>
```

And then supply the dynamic value for your order id and product id.

You can hit api using fetch. [More info](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)

You can simply take some variables in your front end app. As I don't know how your order id and product id are being generated so you need to check on that and then something like,

```
let orderId = someValue
let productId = someOtherValue
let url = "http://localhost:3000/orders/"+orderId+"/"+productId
```

But I think the concern would be GET and POST method. Right now you have `app.post` but the params are in URL so instead you should go for GET method i.e. `app.get`

Comment: @ gprathour Exactly my point! but how do I create a UI in the react App that places both the <order-id-here> and the <product-id-here> and finally sending to the backend API

Comment: Thanks @gprathour, I will make use of your suggestion and will give feedback